# Transforming a list of elements into 2-level nested structure

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

My input XML document is a simple list of items. The number of items is arbitrary:

```
<items>
  <item name="item1"/>
  <item name="item2"/>
  <item name="item3"/>
  ...
  <item name="itemX"/>
</items>
```

Now, I want to split this list into HTML tables. The number of rows and columns are given as parameter values:

```
<xsl:param name="rows"/>
<xsl:param name="cols"/>
```

If we let rows be 3, and cols be 2, the resulting HTML should look like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>item1</td>
    <td>item2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item3</td>
    <td>item4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item5</td>
    <td>item6</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>item7</td>
    <td>item8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item9</td>
    <td>item10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item11</td>
    <td>item12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
...
```

The number of `<table>`s created is thus `ceil(number_of_items / rows / cols)`

I have a basic idea how to solve this, but I can't seem to get the last tweaks right. The following stylesheet produces something close to what I want, but item 4, 7, 10 and 13 are duplicated.
Does anyone have a better idea about how to do this?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="cols" select="2"/>
<xsl:param name="rows" select="3"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <html>
    <head/>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[position() mod ($cols * $rows) = 1]" mode="table"/>
     </body>
   </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="table">
    <table border="1" id="{@name}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="row"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[position() &gt; 1 and position() mod $rows = 0]" mode="row"/>
     </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="row">
    <tr id="{@name}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="cell"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[position() &lt; $cols]" mode="cell"/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="cell">
    <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: are you able to use xslt 2.0 insted of 1.0 ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, at least not without a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add +1 to $cols like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="row">
<tr id="{@name}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="cell"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[position() &lt; ($cols +1)]" mode="cell"/>
</tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this for the table template (you have to limit the amount of items per table):

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="table">
<xsl:variable name="mypos" select="position()"/>
<table border="1" id="{@name}" test="{$mypos}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="row"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[position() &gt; 1 and position() mod  $rows = 0 and position() &lt; $mypos * ($cols * $rows)]" mode="row"/>
 </table>
```

Comment: The `+1` gave me just more duplicates, but with `-1` it's pretty close now. With 13 items, rows = 3 and cols = 4, I get the last item (`item13`) as an unwanted row on the first `<table>`, in addition to its own table: http://jsfiddle.net/M4czG/

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pRows" select="3"/>
 <xsl:param name="pCols" select="2"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vItemsInTable" select="$pRows*$pCols"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
       <xsl:apply-templates mode="table"
            select="*[position() mod $vItemsInTable =1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item" mode="table">
  <table>
   <xsl:apply-templates  mode="row" select=
    "(.|following-sibling::*)
       [not(position() > $vItemsInTable) and position() mod $pCols = 1]">
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item" mode="row">
  <tr>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
     ".|following-sibling::*[not(position() > $pCols -1)]"/>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item">
  <td><xsl:apply-templates select="@name"/></td>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided one, extended to be made more challenging):

```
<items>
    <item name="item1"/>
    <item name="item2"/>
    <item name="item3"/>   ...
    <item name="item4"/>
    <item name="item5"/>
    <item name="item6"/>   ...
    <item name="item7"/>
    <item name="item8"/>
    <item name="item9"/>   ...
    <item name="item10"/>   ...
    <item name="item11"/>   ...
    <item name="item12"/>   ...
    <item name="itemX"/>
</items>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>item3</td>
      <td>item4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>item5</td>
      <td>item6</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>item7</td>
      <td>item8</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>item9</td>
      <td>item10</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>item11</td>
      <td>item12</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>itemX</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```